# Libnetconf Write to Running Datastore from transapi_init function

Tags: c

The question is relating netopeer,libnetconf,transapi
http://libnetconf.googlecode.com/git/doc/doxygen/html/index.html

I am using libnetconf transapi to create a module that automatically initializes its datastore with some values.

As soon as the netopeer-server is started the module is loaded in and the transapi_init function is called.

I want to write to Running Datastore from transapi_init function.

My following transapi_init function return's error "Invalid configuration data for  operation".

```
int transapi_init(xmlDocPtr *running)
{
        xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;
        xmlNodePtr root;
        xmlNsPtr ns;

        doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
        xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, BAD_CAST "activation", NULL));
        ns = xmlNewNs(root, BAD_CAST "urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:ucpe", NULL);
        xmlSetNs(root, ns);

        xmlNewChild(root, root->ns, BAD_CAST "serial-number", BAD_CAST "test serial 1");
        xmlNewChild(root, root->ns, BAD_CAST "activation-code", BAD_CAST "test activation 1");

        nc_rpc_editconfig(NC_DATASTORE_STARTUP, NC_DATASTORE_CONFIG, 0, 0, 0, doc);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My yang model is :

```
module ucpe{
        yang-version 1;
        namespace "urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:ucpe";
        prefix "ucpe";

        container activation{
                description "Ucpe Activation Data";
                leaf serial-number {
                        description "serial number";
                        type string;
                        config "true";
                }

                leaf activation-code {
                        description "Activation code";
                        type string;
                        config "true";
                }
        }
}
```

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What language is it? You have chosen only one tag, and it is even one which doesn't have a description.

Comment: updated.Sorry i can't find tags related to this query.